# Reading barcode in an ios application in .net8 without maui

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, barcode, .net-8.0, ios-camera

We are using Zxing.net.mobile to read barcode in a Xamarin.iOS  application. I get the following error when I debug in iPhone 15 pro.
"System.NotSupportedException: "humanFullBody" has no associated enum value on this platform.'"

Anyway we thought of migrating the Xamarin.iOS project to .net 8 SDK.  Everything works fine with the migration except the Zxing.net.mobile.
System.NotSupportedException: Use the platform specific implementation instead!
at ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Scan(MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options)

I can't use Zxing.net.maui as its not a maui application. I would like to know how else I can read a barcode in an iOS application in .net 8 that does not use maui.

Update:
I still tried adding the zxing.net.maui.controls package.  I get the following 3 errors when i try to build.

Error       Failed to AOT compile ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1. iOS C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    1214
Error       Failed to AOT compile ZXing.Net.MAUI.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1.  iOS C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    1214
Error       Failed to AOT compile aot-instances.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1.   iOS C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    1214

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using Zxing.net.maui even though it's for MAUI and not specifically for iOS? Consider that under the hood MAUI uses .NET iOS, Android etc., so I would give it a chance.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  And iOS has native barcode APIs you should be able to use

Comment: @Jason, Can you point me to the native barcode APIs I could use? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional details, do not stuff it into the comments